# Get reference to View when Content returns the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have a custom control that is trying to autosize itself. Problem is the .Content property is being set automatically behind the scenes to a ViewModel.  I need the control to be able to access the actual View to see what width and height are set to.

How do I get a handle to the View when the .Content is set to a ViewModel?

Comment: Isn't your custom control the view?

Comment: You might want to restate the question.  What do you mean by getting a handle to the View?

Comment: For example, I have a modal window dialog.  In the loaded event for that window, I want to get the top level control/content it's rendering, I check the .Content property of the window, but it's not my view or the most top level grid that is being rendered, but instead, it's returning the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Controls already auto-size based on the type of panel they are in.

For example, if your control is in a `Grid` it will auto-size itself to stretch and fill the entire space available to it. If your control is in a `StackPanel`, it will auto-size itself to take up whatever space it needs, or in other words whatever space it's Content takes up.

So if you want your control to be the same size as whatever it's content is, don't set a size on it and either place your `UserControl` in a panel that doesn't stretch it's children, such as a `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyUserControl />
</StackPanel>
```

or wrap it's `Content` in a control that doesn't stretch it's children.

```
<UserControl ....>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I understand that controls can autosize themselves. The issue is that I have a view with width and height set to Auto. So when I display a viewmodel that renders through that view in my main app's tab, it auto fits correctly.  However, sometimes via a custom lookup control that throws up a modal dialog (also set to auto width and height), and I render the same view there, now a modal dialog with everything auto renders HUGE!!!!! I'm trying to get a handle to that view so that if the width and height are auto, I can change the site to be smaller then main app window and centered.

Comment: @happyfirst Why not set a Max Height/Width on your dialog?

Comment: I tried that. I thought I was hopefully setting a max width and height and yet still opened huge.